# Clarification required regarding the qnorm() function of R

Tags: r, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

It is mentioned [here](https://cosmosweb.champlain.edu/people/stevens/WebTech/R/Chapter-6-R.pdf) that `qnorm(k (in decimal form), mean = μ, sd = σ, lower.tail=TRUE)` finds the `x-value` that separates the bottom `k%` of the values from a distribution with mean `μ` and standard deviation `σ`. So does that bottom `k%` also include the probability value associated with the `x-value` given by the `qnorm()` function?

I am asking this because if CDF is represented by F, then the inverse CDF outputs the value `x` associated with the probability `F(x)` or `P(X ≤ x)` for a random variable `X`.

Also, is it correct to state the following about the output x-value?

> x = F_inverse(F(x)) or F_inverse(P(X ≤ x)) is the default case as
> lower.tail argument is set to TRUE. If set to FALSE, then it will be
> F_inverse(P(X > x)).

Answer (score 3):

**YES, BECAUSE THAT PROBABILITY IS ZERO**

The normal distribution is continuous, so the probability of any particular value is zero. Thus, $P(X\le x)=P(X<x)$, as $P(X=x)=0$.